# How do I access a prefab and all of its instantiated clones in c# and unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a little help again please. I'm currently working on powerups and it's setup so that the powerup affectsthe prefab thats put into its prefab slot, so this is means it is currently only affecting one object (in my case, enemy). When the game starts I spawn about 20 enemies and if i pickup the powerup I want it to affect all those spawned enemies and not only the one that is dragged onto the script, does anyone have a solution or alternate method to do this please?

Comment: What exactly do your code when you power up ? Is your all enemies have same stats or is it depend on enemy ? Can you show some code and part you want to change ?

Comment: I am moving them by using the Vector2.MoveTowards() and I have a speed variable that modifies their movement speed, so I want the power up to set all the enemies's speed to a fixed amount. (Every enemy's speed should be decreased or inceased by the same amount, so yes their stats will be exactly the same.

Comment: Then you can also make speed variable static, thus all would use same speed variable.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiate them store them in a list and then iterate through all and update their value

In your case e.g.

```
// if enemies have a certain Component rather use that type here instead of GameObject
public GameObject enemyPrefab;
// and use the same type here instead of GameObject
private List<GameObject> enemyInstances = new List<GameObject> enemyInstances;

private void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var newEnemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab);
        enemyInstances.Add(newEnemy);
    }
}
```

and then later

```
public void UpdateEnemies()
{
    foreach(var enemy in enemyInstances)
    {
        // skip already destroyed objects
        if(!enemy) continue;

        // whatever to be done to the enemies
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all game objects to an array you can use the [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html).

Just add an 'Enemy' tag to the prefab and use the code below:

```
public GameObject[] enemys;

void Start()
    {
        respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    }
```

Full Unity documentation [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this now